# I want to close an open menu li onclick of the child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jQuery code works, but I want to close the child `ul` only if I click on it (the child `ul`); right now it is closing when I click the parent `li` as well. How can I fix this behavior?

http://jsfiddle.net/c4k5w/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$("ul>li").click(function(){
    var lk=$(this).text();
    var w=$("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").width();
    $("ul li").removeClass("h");
    $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").addClass("h");
    if(w>200){var a=1;$("ul li").removeClass("h");}else{var a=0;}       
    if(a==1){
        $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"') ul").hide(function(){
        $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").animate({width:"200px"},"fast");      
        });         
    }else{  
            $("ul li ul").hide();
            $("ul>li").animate({width:"200px"},"fast");
            $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").animate({width:"1200px"},"fast",function(){
            $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')>ul").slideDown();
        });
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to `return false` for `click` event for children `ul`.

So do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $("ul>li").click(function(){
        var lk=$(this).text();
        var w=$("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").width();
        $("ul li").removeClass("h");
        $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").addClass("h");
        if(w>200){var a=1;$("ul li").removeClass("h");}else{var a=0;}       
        if(a==1){
            $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"') ul").hide(function(){
            $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").animate({width:"200px"},"fast");      
            });         
        }else{  
                $("ul li ul").hide();
                $("ul>li").animate({width:"200px"},"fast");
                $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')").animate({width:"1200px"},"fast",function(){
                $("ul li:contains('"+lk+"')>ul").slideDown();
            });
        }
    }).children().click(function(e) {
      return false;
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c4k5w/4/)**